# How to call a plsql procedure with a table type as input parameter in Java?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have a procedure like

```
  PROCEDURE merge_string_custom_fields(s1_cf IN wf__custom_fields_table, s2__cf IN wf__custom_fields_table, r__cf OUT wf__custom_fields_table);
```

And I try to call it from my Java Code, I read some examples here but if I do something with

```
ArrayDescriptor arrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor
```

I got

"ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionat"

If I try it with

```
((OracleConnection) con).createOracleArray...
```

I got a operation not supported exception.

How I can call my procedure? I Use 11g

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using simple jdbc to call procedure ... Unwrap the connection in the below way.

```
OracleConnection connection = uploadCall.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```